Need help in scrolling into newly added element React
I am having issue in scrolling into dynamically added section. I am able to get the diff between previous value and current value. How do i achieve this. Suggestion or help would be great.
configuredFilters data
[{element: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: Symbol(react.fragment), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …},label: "Carrier SCAC",position: 28},{element: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: Symbol(react.fragment), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
        label: "Carrier SCAC",
        position: 29}]

Component
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}


export const FilterList: React.FC<FiltersInterface> = ({
  configuredFilters,
}) => {
  const ref = useRef<any>();
  const prevConfiguredFilters = usePrevious(configuredFilters);
  console.log("prevConfiguredFilters", configuredFilters, prevConfiguredFilters)
  useEffect(() => {
    if(prevConfiguredFilters !== configuredFilters) {
      if (ref.current) {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
      }
    }
     
  }, [configuredFilters, prevConfiguredFilters])

  return (
    <div className="someclass">
      <div className="someclass">
        {Object.entries(configuredFilters).map(
          ([filterKey, filter]: any, index) => (
            <div key={filterKey} className="FilterWrapper" ref={ref}>
              {filter.element}
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}```



To ensure that scrolling occurs specifically to the newly added element, you could modify your code to assign refs dynamically to each element and then decide which ref to scroll to based on the changes detected in your list.
